# Raspberry Pi + Camera + FFMPEG Youtube -> How to add 2nd Output RTSP

Tags: video, ffmpeg, nas, raspberry-pi, streaming

I am successfully streaming from my Raspi to Youtube using this command line found on GitHub:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -vf -hf -fps 30 -b 6000000 | ffmpeg -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<SESSION>
```

- I know that ffmpeg supports multiple outputs.
- I want to create a 2nd output in addition to the youtube stream that outputs a stream copy to rtsp.
- I want to be able to add this rtsp stream as an IP camera in
  my Synology Surveillance station
- I think the output format must be h264 to work with the NAS.
- The 2nd output should also stream the full 1080p/30fps (same as youtube output) and as my other IP cams do.

How do I need to modify the above command line to achieve the 2nd stream output that can be added to my Synology Surveillance Station as an IP camera.

Thanks in advance, hope this community can solve my problem :)